# Ruby on Rails: Login through Twitter Bootstrap Modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise

I've searched the web for this for some time and I can't seem to find a solution.
I got Ruby on Rails with the Devise authentication gem installed. I am using Twitter Bootstrap for some nice and quick layout stuff and I was wondering how to log in through a Bootstrap Modal.

Now, I made the Modal and it pops up when I press some button on my page. It shows me a nice login form (created with Devise components) and it logs in when I enter my login credentials. All working out great, until I make a mistake by trying to login with an invalid username/password. Devise routes me to a login page (/users/sign_in) on which it shows the error that I entered an invalid username/password.

Since this is not very smooth and nice, I wanted to show the error inside the Bootstrap Modal instead of redirecting to some login page.

I already changed the submit button of the form so it doesn't submit anymore, but links to this javascript instead:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function check_credentials() {
    if(check_form() == true) {
        $("#new_user").submit();
    } else {
        document.getElementById("alert_box").style.display = "block";
    }
}

function check_form() {
    if(true) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
</script>
```

*check_credentials*: entry point of script
Will call the check_form function and either logs in (on returning true) or displays the alert_box for showing the error (on returning false).

*check_form*:
**HAS** to check if the entered credentials are correct (using a mysql database for checking against registered users) and return true if they do, otherwise false.

As you probably already have noticed, this isn't going to work, since the check_form function isn't implemented. This is because I got stuck here, I need to use the Devise login credential checker to check if the entered credentials are correct. So I started looking for the Devise controllers ({Ruby install dir}\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\devise-2.2.3\app\controllers\devise) and since I'm still a newbie with Ruby, I really can't make anything of it.

Can someone please help me with either calling the right Devise function for checking credentials or creating a new function who does this for me?

If more info is needed or if something is rather unclear, just ask me and I'll do as much as I can to add this info.

Thank you for your time and help!

Cheers, Patrick

Comment: Is there no one who can help me with this? :(

Comment: Anyone who can help me out at least a bit?